# How to concatenate two columns that have alias PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, concatenation

I just started with **PL/SQL** and I am not very clear about the concept of concatenating so now I have the need to concatenate the result of two columns that have aliases and show the result of this in one.

The following are the queries I make with their respective aliases:

```
(SELECT SPRCMNT_TEXT
        FROM SPRCMNT
        WHERE SPRCMNT_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM
        AND SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE = '15'
        AND SPRCMNT_ORIG_CODE = 'FTDF') FOLIO_CONTROL,

(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR, 'Profesionista="([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
        FROM SPRCMNT
        WHERE SPRCMNT_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM
        AND SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE = '15'
        AND SPRCMNT_ORIG_CODE = 'FTDF') PROFESIONISTA,
```

What I need is to concatenate the alias of `PROFESIONISTA+FOLIO_CONTROL` and its result display it in a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries are the same excepted for the `from` clause, so I think that you want:

```
SELECT 
    SPRCMNT_TEXT 
    || REGEXP_SUBSTR(SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR, 'Profesionista="([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) res
FROM SPRCMNT
WHERE 
    SPRCMNT_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM 
    AND SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE = '15' 
    AND SPRCMNT_ORIG_CODE = 'FTDF'
```

This gives you a result with a single column, called `res`, with the two strings concatenated (which is what operator `||` does in Oracle).

You might want to add a separator:

```
    SPRCMNT_TEXT 
    || ' -- '
    || REGEXP_SUBSTR(SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR, 'Profesionista="([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) res
```